# ADFS 2.0 - request token for service in different AD

Tags: certificate, wif, adfs2.0

I have the following scenario:

Active Directory 1: WCF Client, ADFS 2.0 (STS)

Active Directory 2: WCF service (Relying Party)

I have added the RP to the ADFS but when I request a token from the ADFS I recieve the following error: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized.

Looking at the event log of the ADFS I find the matching error:

> An error occurred during an attempt to build the certificate chain for
>   the relying party trust 'http://XXXXX/Service1/' certificate
>   identified by thumbprint 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'. Possible causes are that the
>   certificate has been revoked, the certificate chain could not be
>   verified as specified by the relying party trust's encryption
>   certificate revocation settings or certificate is not within its
>   validity period.
>
> You can use Windows PowerShell commands for AD FS 2.0 to configure the
>   revocation settings for the relying party encryption certificate. 
>   Relying party trust's encryption certificate revocation settings:
>   CheckChainExcludeRoot  The following errors occurred while building
>   the certificate chain:   Unknown error. Unknown error.
>
> User Action:  Ensure that the relying party trust's encryption
>   certificate is valid and has not been revoked.  Ensure that AD FS 2.0
>   can access the certificate revocation list if the revocation setting
>   does not specify "none" or a "cache only" setting.   Verify your proxy
>   server setting. For more information about how to verify your proxy
>   server setting, see the AD FS 2.0 Troubleshooting Guide
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=182180).

Looks like the ADFS does not trust the signing certificate from the RP (understandable, the CA which issued the Signing certificate is in a different AD).
The CertificateRevokationList is reachable from both Active Directories.

I have added the CA certificate to the Trusted Root Certificates of the "Local Computer", but I think the problem is the validation mechanism.

What do I have to configure to get the ADFS to issue a token signed with the proper certificate or how can I convince the ADFS that the certificate is valid?

**EDIT:**

I have tried changing the revokation check with the powershell command:

```
 Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust  -SigningCertificateRevocationCheck CheckEndCert
```

but with no luck:
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

```
At line:1 char:26
+ Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust <<<<   -SigningCertificateRevocationCheck CheckEndCert
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.IdentityServer.PowerShell.Commands.SetRelyingPartyTrustC
   ommand
```

**EDIT 2**:
This worked:

```
(Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust) | Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust  -EncryptionCertificateRevocationCheck CheckEndCert
```

but now my client in Active Directory 1 complains about the certificate...

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: SOAP
>   security negotiation with
>   'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Service1/' for target
>   'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Service1/' failed.  See inner exception for
>   more details. --->
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: The
>   X.509 certificate CN=RP-Service chain building failed. The certificate
>   that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the
>   certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. A certificate
>   chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to add your RP-Service cert into Trusted People store on the machine, where your WCF client runs. That was what I did when using self-signed cert to test WCF call under federation with ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same error. What helps is using

```
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust  -EncryptionCertificateRevocationCheck None
```

But this will only disable the check on the RP part. Since we're talking about federation the same will happen on the federated server. So you have to do it there too. Anyways, it only changed the errors i get - i still can't federate ATM.

Comment: This is what I wrote in my EDIT 2. You can also try to set the check to CheckEndCert.

Answer (score 0):

The command that works for me is this:

```
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust  -TargetName <relyingpartytrustName> -EncryptionCertificateRevocationCheck None
```

We have several times, resulted to installing the signing and encryption certificates (self-signed certs generated by ADFS) everywhere (i.e. the servers hosting the WCF services).